# How do I convert “thm conjI” to an ASCII string I can save to a file?

Tags: isabelle

From [*The Isabelle Cookbook*](http://www.inf.kcl.ac.uk/staff/urbanc/Cookbook/), pages 11 and 12, I found some beginning information related to what I'm trying to do.

Representative of what I'm trying to do is this ML statement:

```
val syntax_str = Syntax.string_of_term @{context} (prop_of @{thm conjI});
```

I want to save the theorem `conjI` to a file as an ASCII string, and have it look like this:

```
P \<Longrightarrow> Q \<Longrightarrow> P \<and> Q
```

Below, I show some of the ML commands I experimented with from [src/Pure/General/pretty.ML](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/8f4a332500e4/src/Pure/General/pretty.ML) and [src/Pure/Syntax/syntax.ML](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/8f4a332500e4/src/Pure/Syntax/syntax.ML).

I can get a string, but it's not good for saving to a file. I don't know how to get the string as what's saved to a THY file.

```
ML‹Syntax.pretty_term›
ML‹Syntax.pretty_term @{context} (prop_of @{thm conjI})›
ML‹Pretty.writeln (Syntax.pretty_term @{context} (prop_of @{thm conjI}))›
ML‹Pretty.string_of (Syntax.pretty_term @{context} (prop_of @{thm conjI}))›
ML‹Pretty.symbolic_output (Syntax.pretty_term @{context} (prop_of @{thm conjI}))›
ML‹Pretty.symbolic_string_of (Syntax.pretty_term @{context} (prop_of @{thm conjI}))›
ML‹Pretty.str_of (Syntax.pretty_term @{context} (prop_of @{thm conjI}))›

ML‹
  val syntax_str = Syntax.string_of_term @{context} (prop_of @{thm conjI});
  writeln syntax_str;
  File.write (Path.explode (
    File.platform_path(Resources.master_directory @{theory}) ^ 
    "/syntax_str.txt")) syntax_str;
› 
ML‹
  val pretty_str = Pretty.str_of (
    Syntax.pretty_term @{context} (prop_of @{thm conjI}));
  writeln pretty_str;
  File.write (Path.explode (
    File.platform_path(Resources.master_directory @{theory}) ^ 
    "/pretty_str.txt")) pretty_str;
›
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do with these strings after saving them to disk? If it is just for machine consumption, you may want to store the YXML representation of a term.

Comment: @Lars, I want to create an appendix of theorems for my PDF document. The eventual plan is to find many or all theorem names used in `apply`, `by`, etc statements, create a THY with ML defined to save the theorem formulas to a THY, where Isabelle will be run on the THY. With that, I'll create a LaTeX appendix of theorems so that, in my PDF, I can click on a theorem name in a proof to take me to the formula in the appendix. Getting the formulas in the ASCII form that's used in THY files is what I need. It's to make the reading of proofs in the PDF decently independent of the software.

Comment: I think there is a better way for that: Inside a text block, you can use `@{thm myThmName}` antiquotation to print a theorem. Have a look at the `Document Preparation` chapter in the reference manual, in particular the `Document Antiquotations` sections.

Comment: @Lars, I tried to use the LaTeX of Isabelle in 2011, and I couldn't do what I wanted, which is to put all Isar in a verbatim environment. So, I've gone a different path to creating LaTeX, which now involves my own markup in a THY. It's not that my ways are that good, it's that I'm now inclined to not want to work with LaTeX via Isabelle. I already do search and replace for all symbols that I use, like `\<and>`, and I have my own LaTeX preamble. I'd be happy for pros like you to give me sophisticated solutions, but I have a few ideas that Isabelle can't implement, and a hack is good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the *best* way, but you could try:

```
fun render_thm ctxt thm =
  Print_Mode.setmp ["xsymbols"]
    (fn _ => Display.pretty_thm ctxt thm
             |> Pretty.str_of
             |> YXML.parse_body
             |> XML.content_of) ()
```

Now, if you run:

```
ML {* render_thm @{context} @{thm iffI} *}
```

you will get a string that displays in Isabelle/jEdit as:

```
⟦?P ⟹ ?Q; ?Q ⟹ ?P⟧ ⟹ ?P = ?Q
```

but internally is actually:

```
\<lbrakk>?P \<Longrightarrow> ?Q; ?Q \<Longrightarrow> ?P\<rbrakk> \<Longrightarrow> ?P = ?Q
```

This latter version is what you will get if you save the string to a file using `File.write`.

Comment: David, thanks. I can do some processing on what's saved to get it like I want it.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look in the sledgehammer code (essentially the function `string_of_isar_proof` in `~~/src/HOL/Tools/Sledgehammer/sledgehammer_isar_proof.ML`) and here is what I manage to put together to make it working:

```
ML ‹ fun term_to_xsymbols ctxt0 t = 
  let val ctxt = ctxt0
    |> Config.put show_markup false
    |> Config.put Printer.show_type_emphasis false
    |> Config.put show_types false
    |> Config.put show_sorts false
    |> Config.put show_consts false
    |> Config.put show_question_marks false
  in
    t
    |> singleton (Syntax.uncheck_terms ctxt)
    |> Sledgehammer_Isar_Annotate.annotate_types_in_term ctxt
    |> Sledgehammer_Util.with_vanilla_print_mode (Syntax.unparse_term ctxt #> Pretty.string_of)
    |> Sledgehammer_Util.simplify_spaces
  end
 ›


ML‹
  val pretty_str = term_to_xsymbols @{context} (prop_of @{thm conjI});
  writeln pretty_str;
  File.write (Path.explode (
    File.platform_path(Resources.master_directory @{theory}) ^ 
    "/pretty_str.txt")) pretty_str;
›
```

Output in Isabelle/jedit:

```
⟦P; Q⟧ ⟹ P ∧ Q
val pretty_str = "⟦P; Q⟧ ⟹ P ∧ Q": string
```

Output in the text file:

```
\<lbrakk>P; Q\<rbrakk> \<Longrightarrow> P \<and> Q
```

Comment: Mathieu, thanks. I have to choose one answer, and David's is a little shorter, but your answer has brought to my attention that Sledgehammer does a lot or processing to display its proofs, so knowing about `sledgehammer_isar_proof.ML` might be useful for me in the future. Also, I might want to set the `show` options like you're doing.

Comment: Sure, no problem, I would choose the David's one too. I have just seen it after having written mine.

Comment: Note that the code in sledgehammer contains a lot of thought to ensure that the parser reconstructs the same term as was pretty printed (which is probably still not 100%). The standard pretty printing is far from that.